# Clojurescript: subscribe on events of custom javascript object

Tags: clojurescript

I import one js library from node_modules in clojurescript and create an object `provider` using it. Now I need to subscribe on events of this object. This is javascript code:

```
provider.on("disconnect", (error: { code: number; message: string }) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

How can I do the same in clojurescript? I tried this:

```
(.on provider "disconnect" #(js/console.log "disconnected"))
```

and this:

```
(.on provider #js {:event "disconnect"} #(js/console.log "disconnected"))
```

but it does not work.

Comment: the first one looks about right, but what does not work? How does it fail?

Comment: Just no reaction on event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first one is right, it works, I had the problem, because the event didn't arise.